# If I put an argument in my default constructor, but give the argument a default value, is it still really a default constructor?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, dllexport

I know it's said to be a default constructor, but how does it work behind the scenes? I'm getting a "procedure entry point could not be located" error when my program tries to use my library containing class A with this default constructor. The program doesn't even use the default constructor of class A; it uses other constructors of the A. The library builds fine; the program builds fine. The DLL has been rebuilt, so it should know its own method call when it sees it. I'm actually just completely lost.

```
class DLLEXPORT A
{
  A(int a = 0);  //default constructor and single parameter constructor
};
```

Comment: "A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that can be called without an argument."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A default constructor is *any* constructor that is *callable* with no arguments.

When you say `A x;`, then this is the same as `A x(0);`, which is what the compiler actually calls.

Similarly, copy constructors can have additional, defaulted arguments.